# Unable to add member to GitHub

Tags: github

I am trying to add a new member to an existing team in GitHub. The new employee I am trying to add created his GitHub account yesterday. 
When I type in his GitHub account ID to add him as member, his GitHub ID doesn’t populate in the look-ahead list .

I created a new test account and I was immediately able to see the account in the member list.

There is no difference between the test account and the account the new employee created.

Can anyone tell me what may be causing this new member not to show up in the lookahead list GitHub?

Answer (score 3):

This happened to us last week. The user needs to validate their GitHub account email first.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user to login to github and keep the session active, and then try to add the users to team. This worked for me.